# UI5 Binding Data to XML Table

Tags: binding, sapui5

I have a JSON "string" (if that makes sense), which I am trying to bind to a table but it is not showing the items.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing what I mean.

http://jsbin.com/ziboh/17/edit

Is the reason for it not working because it is a JSON String and not a true JSON object.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsbin.com/xekapaheve/1/edit?html,js,output (I just added the JSON.parse())

Answer (score 2):

JSONModel works with JSON data. If your data is in a string format you can use JSON.parse(your data text) but if possible try to keep your data in JSON format.

Please see http://jsbin.com/nuhijemape/2/edit